# How to force delete files in the folder automatically without pressing Y to make sure in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following batch program, `uninstall.bat`

```
@echo off
cls

cd\
del /f "c:\system\folder\*"
cls
echo uninstall successful
pause
exit
```

when i am running this program it asks,

```
c:\system\folder\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

But, i don't want these warning prompts.
i want it to delete without asking `Are you sure` warning message.

Note: i must need force delete option `/f`

Please help me guys. Lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever read the help text that appears when you type `del /?` into a command prompt window?

Comment: Your question is not about a Batch file, but about the `del` command...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
del "c:\system\folder\*" /f /q /s
```

`/Q` is for Quiet, so no prompts
`/S` is to delete all subfolders also (if you want this)

Complete option syntax can be found over here: https://ss64.com/nt/del.html

Answer (score 0):

Typing `DEL /?` into a Command Prompt would have yielded:

```bat
    /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
```

Therefore as you are using the wildcard **`*`**:

```bat
@ECHO Off
CLS
DEL /F /Q "C:\system\folder\*" 2>NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO uninstall successful
PAUSE
EXIT
```